# java -PDFBox how to extract text from documents without storing in an array?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to extract text from PDF documents. Then once, extracted, I will insert those text into a table in MySQL.

The code:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path1));

if (!document.isEncrypted()) {
    PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
    String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        String sql="insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";

        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (String word : words) {
            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
            // insert every word directly to table db
            word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);

            /* preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.print("Add ");*/

            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            i++;
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                System.out.print("Add Thousand");
            }
        }

        if (i > 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            System.out.print("Add Remaining");
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine but as you can see if the document is large and has like 10 million words inside it, the `lines[]` is not gonna do any justice and will throw `out of memory exception`.

I can't think of a solution to this.
Is there any way I could just extract and insert the words directly to the db or it's not possible?

EDITED :

This is what I did:

processText method :

```
public void processText(String text) throws SQLException {

    String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");


        String sql="insert IGNORE into  test.indextable values (?,?);";


        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (String word : words) {

            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
            // insert every word directly to table db
            word=word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);



            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            i++;
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                System.out.print("Add Thousand");
            }




        }




        if (i > 0) {
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            System.out.print("Add Remaining");

        }

    }
    preparedStatement.close();
    System.out.println("Successfully commited changes to the database!");

}
```

index method (calling the above method):

```
public void index() throws Exception {
       // Connection con1 = con.connect();
        try {

            // Connection con1=con.connect();
           // Connection con1 = con.connect();
            Statement statement = con1.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active' LIMIT 5");


            while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                 path1 = rs.getString(2);
               int getNum = rs.getInt(1);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                //updateProcess_DB(getNum);
                Statement test = con1.createStatement();
                test.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where UniqueID="+getNum);



                try {
                    // call the index function


                    /*Indexing process = new Indexing();

                    process.index(path1);*/

                    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path1));

                    if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                        PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                        for(int p=1; p<=document.getNumberOfPages();++p) {
                            tStripper.setStartPage(p);
                            tStripper.setEndPage(p);
                            String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                            processText(pdfFileInText);
                        }


                        }
```

Comment: Why not working page by page? I.e. set the start and end page each time.

Comment: @Tilman That's essentially the answer I was just going to write... I assume the OP is not aware of the option to extract from a limited range of page only...

Comment: Can you give me a general idea of working page by page? I am still unfamiliar with PDFBox.

Comment: `stripper.setStartPage(startPage); stripper.setEndPage(endPage);` note that they are 1-based. So do this for 1... <= `doc.getNumberOfPages()` and call `tStripper.getText(document);` each time.

Comment: Put where? Perhaps you could post your solution below so it's easier to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code uses the string `pdfFileInText` which is gathered from `tStripper.getText(document);` and gets the whole document at once. First refactor all what you do with this string (it starts with `pdfFileInText.split`) in a separate method, e.g. `processText`. Then change your code to this:

```
PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
for (int p = 1; p <= document.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
{
    stripper.setStartPage(p); // 1-based
    stripper.setEndPage(p); // 1-based
    String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
    processText(pdfFileInText);
}
```

The new code processes each page separately. This way you'll be able to do the database inserts in smaller steps and you won't have to store all the words of the documents, only the words of one page.

Comment: So it will extract all words in one page,then insert to db, and then extract the next page, and repeat the cycle?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Could you check my edited post if i done it correctly?

Comment: I tried doing it with 10 million words in a document and it stills throw out of memory error : java heap space. How do i fix it?

Comment: Is it because in your solution above, it did not empty out the string after each page?

Comment: No per your other question (that the problem is really in `load()`, and no because this is a loop so the string gets overwritten.

Comment: I see. My senior actually told me if there is a possible way to "open" the file instead of "load" it. I said no as what you said earlier there isn't such option. He doubted me lol.

Comment: Is there a way I can "save" the pdf file into a text file and process the text from .txt instead? I'm asking because you seem to be expertise in this

Comment: He doesn't have to believe me LOL. Opening a file is not the same as opening and reading the structures (which is what we do). You could try Adobe Reader and simply select all and then save as text. You could also try the same with PDF.js ( https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html ). If you have access to Adobe Acrobat you could split it in 2. Same with PDFSam if it works.

Comment: I forgot to answer comment 3, your edited post is fine. (But you could test this yourself using a small file)

Comment: What you senior may not know is that PDF isn't something like HTML where all is in sequence, i.e. page1, page 2, page 3 etc. PDF is a sometimes complex bunch of structures and some may be referenced by several objects. Try opening the file with NOTEPAD++, unless the file is uncompressed you'll see gibberish.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Since I am new to PDFBox library and studied some of the API on their documentation, I just wanna be extra clear on this, hence I asked you.  So if i were to keep using PDFBox, I am f*cked right to solve this issue for the size of that pdf file?

Comment: Yes, unless you can bring up a system with enough memory.

Comment: I see. Would you be interested to test it out on your Java IDE if I send the you pdf file with the issue and just use my code to test it?

Comment: Regarding comment 10, yes i tested on smaller files and it works perfectly fine. Only issue is the big file I've been stressing about :(

Comment: Upload the file somewhere and send me the link ( tilman at snafu dot de) don't send the file, only the link.

Comment: Ok no problem. Will do so on monday

Comment: Here is the dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/osyk2ieoq6od2p8/10-million-password-list-top-1000000.pdf?dl=0

Comment: sorry , i didn't send the link to your email , i just sent it here, hope it's fine

Comment: Just one thing, can you confirm the proper way to increase the -Xmx value because I think i might have increase it wrongly , therefore it doesn't work. Do I change the VM options? Because i tried using -xmx 1024m and it's able to print words from page 1- 1000 so i don't know what is going on

Comment: "-Xmx1024m" or "-Xmx1g" is the correct way to do it. No space (I never tried with a space) and the first X is a capital.

Comment: I was able to open the file. Took some time, but less than a minute I think,

Comment: "-Xmx1024m" or "-Xmx1g" is the correct way to do it. No space (I never tried with a space) and the first X is a capital. I was able to open the file. It took some time, but less than a minute. I also ran ExtractText (command line) successfully.